# Should tester be authorised for Internal App sharing to install the app using the link?

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

I shared an Android app using [Internal App Sharing](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/internalappsharing/) and selected "**Anyone you share the link with can download**" in Manage Testers. Internal App sharing also enabled on Google Play Store App

The users with the link can not download the app but users who already joined as a tester can install.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

To make your app available on link, follow these steps:

- sign in to your google play console
- select an app
  -On the left menu, select Development tools > Internal app sharing.
- select the “Authorised testers” tab
- under “ link availability”, select **No email list**

> Important: After adding authorized testers, provide your testers with instructions on how to turn on internal sharing app.

To turn on **internal app sharing**

- open the google play store app.
- Tap Menu > Settings
- In the “about” section, tap the play store version 7 times.
- After the internal app sharing setting appears, tap the switch to turn on internal app sharing.
- Tap turn on.

Comment: Should tester be authorised under manage testers to install the app using the app sharing link?  

App sharing is on and already enabled link availability (selected "Anyone you share the link with can download")

Comment: I think google play changed the name from “authorised testers” to manage testers